# How can I reframe this question to make it more suitable for the Q&A format of SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474715/do-all-web-applications-need-a-browser) on Stack Overflow, wherein I asked if it is possible to launch and interact with a Web Application without using a Web Browser, and how?

Somehow, I also felt that something was amiss in the question and it eventually got closed by moderator as Off Topic. Is there any way I could re-frame the question to garner appropriate response?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. How? Well... where to start. And that's the problem of being so open ended and makes better for a series of blog posts

Comment: So it would help if I narrow down the scope of the question. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Something like "Can i write a web client program in C++? / xyz language? Which library do you prefer?"
But since the question is so open ended, im not even sure if you wanted a programming solution.

Comment: I was in fact unsure if something like that was even possible. I just wanted an insight into the technology to do it and references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you received a few answers, all of which are about as vague as your question.... But still *tried* and answered it.

my advice would be to give an example of what you're trying to accomplish, rather than a more theoretical question. (Be careful with yes or no questions)

what kind of web app are you trying to make, how will it be opened, and any other details would be helpful.

I don't see anything wrong with asking theoretical questions, but some people found this too vague.

the FAQ says if a whole book can be written to answer your question, its probably not well formed.

hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an actual programming problem underlying the question.

You are simply asking for clarification regarding a definition that you have read in "*most of the articles*". Whether or not this definition is correct doesn't seem to be particularly useful information, and is certainly not a practical problem faced by programmers.

In its current form, your question is not in fact asking "*if it is possible to launch and interact with a Web Application without using a Web Browser, and how*". If you were to shift the focus of the question to a specific instance of this problem, the question would not be off topic. For example:

> I am trying to use casper.JS to launch and simulate interaction with
>   [XYZ web application]. Here is the code I am using:
>
> > [some code]
>
> Unfortunately I am running into [some problems].